# How to appropriately display the day of the month by itself? Is 日‪ required, optional, or undesirable?

Tags: translation, computing

I know that an acceptable way to display (this is in a computer program) a full year/month/day date is like so:

> 2013年5月19日‪

What If I wanted to display the day **only**? Does the following look right, OK, or weird to native Japanese user? Is the 日‪ character required, optional, or undesirable in this case?

> 19日‪

In other words, would it look better if it was just the number?

> 19

Comment: It kind of depends on the context. Where and in what kind of app is it? And for the record it's fine to write the date as 2013-5-9 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would be better off using the 日. The same in other language, without unit the number does not mean anything.